# Access array in main by pointers by method in class

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

I need some help with my code, i prepare for my coming exam.

I have code with 3 classes: Package, Person and Courier(inherit from Person).
Then i have array in main with Packages.
And now i'm stuck at some point where i have 'Courier k1(p, p+3);' which means i need to assign to this Courier packages from p to p+3 by pointers. And my problem is that i don't know how to access this all packages i need by method from any class.
Simple example of code:

```
class Package
{
 string _address;
 float _value;
};

class Person
{
 string _name, _lastname;
};

class Courier:public Person
{
vector < Package > tab;
}

int main()
{
  Package p[] = {
    Package("Dabrowskiego 33", 123.00),
    Package("NMP 12", 40.00),
    Package("Armii Krakowej 4", 30.00),
    Package("Andersa 6", 51.00),
    Package("Kukuczki 13", 12.00),
    Package("Skrzyneckiego 5", 40.00),
  };
   Courier k1(p, p+3);
   cout << k1.value() << endl;

return 0;
};
```

Code above is only example, code in main is unchangeable because it's base from teacher.
I tried to make method in Courier with count amount of packages, and then add values to vector like this

```
for(int i=0;i<amount;i++)
            {
                tab.push_back(Package(*(p+i)));
            }
```

I dont know if it's a good way, even possible to do, but then i don't know how to display values by value() function.

Regards

Edit://

Thanks for help everyone, i managed to end my program and everything seems to work. But i have one doubt.

```
Courier k2;
  cout << "---- 8 ----" << endl;
  cout << k2.value() << endl;

  {
    Courier k3(k1);
    cout << "---- 9 ----" << endl;
    cout << k3.value() << endl;

    k2 = k3;
    cout << "---- 10 ----" << endl;
    cout << k2.value() << endl;

    k1 = k1 + p[4];
    k1 = k1 + p[5];

    cout << "---- 11 ----" << endl;
    cout << k1.value() << endl;

  }

  cout << "---- 12 ----" << endl;
  cout << k2.value() << endl;
```

Now i'm concerned. Right now values look like this:

1. 8 - returns 0(as my default constructor set value to 0 if there is no value)
2. 9 - returns 193 as it sums all values
3. 10 - return same as above cuz it assign it from k3
4. 11 - returns 245 because it add 2 values
5. 12 - returns 193.

And now, should it work like this or values 8 and 12 should be the same (equal 0) and only values inside brackets should change?

Comment: You need to add a constructor to `Courier` which takes a pair of pointers to `Package`, and uses them to initialize the `tab` member variable.  You also need to add a `value` function, and do whatever the `value` function is supposed to do.  (Print out the total value of all packages?)

Comment: Please provide [mre], which includes your attempt. Currently it's unclear where the bottom code snippet is placed, in relation to all of the other code.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica You mean "return the total value of all packages". (I think the distinction between "return" and "print" is sometimes a point of confusion for beginners.)

Comment: @aschepler Arwk!  Yes, I meant **return**.  I am no longer a beginner, and really shouldn't be making mistakes like that!

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Yes, I assumed that was just a slip-up. I was just spelling out why I thought it was worth commenting, as opposed to just nitpicking for its own sake.

Comment: Thank you very much for help, i edit my post because i manage to end my program but i have doubt.

Comment: Your additional questions are possibly worth opening a new question. (But why wouldn't `k2.value()` be changed, since the statement `k2 = k3;` did happen earlier?)

Answer (score 2):

First, the line `Courier k1(p, p+3);` implies that class `Courier` has a constructor which accepts two pointer arguments. That would look like:

```
class Courier : public Person
{
public:
    Courier(const Package* first, const Package* last);
private:
    std::vector<Package> tab;
};
```

(If your class hasn't discussed `const` much yet, you can probably safely leave it out for this exercise, since `main` doesn't use it.)

Defining a constructor involves initializing all the base classes and members. In this case, the base class `Person` and the member `tab`.

The code isn't saying anything about a first name or last name, so default-constructing the `Person` base subobject makes sense.

Luckily, `std::vector<T>` already has a constructor which takes a pair of pointers representing a range. It's #5 [on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), the one that looks like

```
template< class InputIt >
vector( InputIt first, InputIt last,
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

since a raw pointer is a type of Input Iterator.

So the constructor definition (as it appears if written outside the class definition):

```
Courier::Courier(const Package* begin, const Package* end)
    : Person(),        /* or just omit the Person() */
      tab(first, last) /* copies all the Packages into the vector */
{}                     /* nothing else to do after tab is initialized */
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a pointer to an object, you can do with it whatever the object will allow. What I think you want something like

```
Courier (Package * current, Package * end)
{
    while (current != end) // loop until the end. Note this could be off by one.
                           // I don't know id the last Package is supposed to be added
    {
        tab.push_back(*current); // copy current Package into vector
        current++; //advance to next Package
    }
}
```

Why

You don't have an `amount`, just a start and end, so you start at the start and look at all of the `Package`s up to the end (possibly including the end package, but this would be unusual). It looks like your instructor may be trying to teach iterators.

Note:

Konrad points out below that this can be reduced to constructing the `vector` more intelligently:

```
Courier (Package * start, Package * end):tab(start, end)
{
}
```

This is the smarter way to fill the `vector`, but it doesn't demonstrate how to iterate through the pointers so it's "less educational."

Comment: This works, but why not just call the appropriate `vector` constructor instead?

Comment: @KonradRudolph because I'm shtupid.